# Python: find all possible word combinations with a sequence of characters (word segmentation)

Tags: python, combinations, permutation, combinatorics

I'm doing some word segmentation experiments like the followings.

`lst` is a sequence of characters, and `output` is all the possible words.

```
lst = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

def foo(lst):
    ...
    return output

output = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
          ['ab', 'c', 'd'],
          ['a', 'bc', 'd'],
          ['a', 'b', 'cd'],
          ['ab', 'cd'],
          ['abc', 'd'],
          ['a', 'bcd'],
          ['abcd']]
```

I've checked `combinations` and `permutations` in `itertools` library,
and also tried [combinatorics](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/combinatorics/1.4.3).
However, it seems that I'm looking at the wrong side because this is not pure permutation and combinations...

It seems that I can achieve this by using lots of loops, but the efficiency might be low.

**EDIT**

The word order is important so combinations like `['ba', 'dc']` or `['cd', 'ab']` are not valid.

The order should always be *from left to right.*

**EDIT**

@Stuart's solution doesn't work in Python 2.7.6

**EDIT**

@Stuart's solution does work in Python 2.7.6, see the comments below.

Comment: See my code working [here](http://ideone.com/ufVuEm) in Python 2.7.3 and [here](http://ideone.com/N4y9t7) in Python 3.2.3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`itertools.product` should indeed be able to help you.

The idea is this:-
Consider A1, A2, ..., AN separated by slabs. There will be N-1 slabs.
If there is a slab there is a segmentation. If there is no slab, there is a join.
Thus, for a given sequence of length N, you should have 2^(N-1) such combinations.

Just like the below

```
import itertools
lst = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
combinatorics = itertools.product([True, False], repeat=len(lst) - 1)

solution = []
for combination in combinatorics:
    i = 0
    one_such_combination = [lst[i]]
    for slab in combination:
        i += 1
        if not slab: # there is a join
            one_such_combination[-1] += lst[i]
        else:
            one_such_combination += [lst[i]]
    solution.append(one_such_combination)

print solution
```

Comment: I choose this answer because it takes the least time, but the others' solutions are also great!

Answer (score 1):

There are 8 options, each mirroring the binary numbers 0 through 7:

```
000
001
010
011
100
101
110
111
```

Each 0 and 1 represents whether or not the 2 letters at that index are "glued" together. 0 for no, 1 for yes.

```
>>> lst = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
... output = []
... formatstr = "{{:0{}.0f}}".format(len(lst)-1)
... for i in range(2**(len(lst)-1)):
...     output.append([])
...     s = "{:b}".format(i)
...     s = str(formatstr.format(float(s)))
...     lstcopy = lst[:]
...     for j, c in enumerate(s):
...         if c == "1":
...             lstcopy[j+1] = lstcopy[j] + lstcopy[j+1]
...         else:
...             output[-1].append(lstcopy[j])
...     output[-1].append(lstcopy[-1])
... output
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
 ['a', 'b', 'cd'],
 ['a', 'bc', 'd'],
 ['a', 'bcd'],
 ['ab', 'c', 'd'],
 ['ab', 'cd'],
 ['abc', 'd'],
 ['abcd']]
>>>
```

Comment: your code isn't working for lst = ['a','b','c','d','e'].

Comment: thanks! fixed it to work for cases with more letters as well. Even if I don't get the accept, this was a fun exercise :)

Comment: ^ Haha! I have upvoted yours. We both have the same solution. You were faster! :-)

Comment: Thanks! Yeah we saw the problem the same way, yours makes good use of the itertools library, I'll read up on it.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from itertools import combinations
a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
a = "".join(a)
cuts = []
for i in range(0,len(a)):
    cuts.extend(combinations(range(1,len(a)),i))
for i in cuts:
    last = 0
    output = []
    for j in i:
        output.append(a[last:j])
        last = j
    output.append(a[last:])
    print(output)
```

output:

```
zsh 2419 % ./words.py  
['abcd']
['a', 'bcd']
['ab', 'cd']
['abc', 'd']
['a', 'b', 'cd']
['a', 'bc', 'd']
['ab', 'c', 'd']
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

Comment: i can't upvote you. i wrote the reason in comment under your answer.  
you code i smaller then mine, that's good, but, on my machine your code dosn't work well :(

Comment: That was actually Stuart's answer, not mine, but Sririam upvoted mine so it's all good.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive generator:

```
def split_combinations(L):
    for split in range(1, len(L)):
        for combination in split_combinations(L[split:]):
            yield [L[:split]] + combination
    yield [L]

print (list(split_combinations('abcd')))
```

Edit. I'm not sure how well this would scale up for long strings and at what point it hits Python's recursion limit. Similarly to some of the other answers, you could also use `combinations` from `itertools` to work through every possible combination of split-points.

```
def split_string(s, t):
    return [s[start:finish] for start, finish in zip((None, ) + t, t + (None, ))]

def split_combinations(s):
    for i in range(len(s)):
        for split_points in combinations(range(1, len(s)), i):
            yield split_string(s, split_points)
```

These both seem to work as intended in Python 2.7 ([see here](http://ideone.com/ufVuEm)) and Python 3.2 ([here](http://ideone.com/N4y9t7)). As @twasbrillig says, make sure you indent it as shown.

Comment: i don't see ['abc' 'd'] in output

Comment: `In [1]: def split_combinations(L):
   ...:         for split in range(1, len(L)):
   ...:                 for combination in split_combinations(L[split:]):
   ...:                         yield [L[:split]] + combination
   ...:                 yield [L]
   ...:             
  

In [2]: print (list(split_combinations('abcd')))
[['a', 'b', 'cd'], ['a', 'bcd'], ['a', 'bcd'], ['abcd'], ['ab', 'cd'], ['abcd'], ['abcd']]`

Comment: `>>> def split_combinations(L):
...     for split in range(1, len(L)):
...         for combination in split_combinations(L[split:]):
...             yield [L[:split]] + combination
...     yield [L]
... print (list(split_combinations('abcd')))
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'cd'], ['a', 'bc', 'd'], ['a', 'bcd'], ['ab', 'c', 'd'], ['ab', 'cd'], ['abc', 'd'], ['abcd']]`

Comment: Python 3.4.0 (default, Apr 11 2014, 13:05:11)

Comment: Python 3.4.1 (default, Aug  7 2014, 13:09:27)

Comment: But I highly doubt that makes the difference ;)

Comment: You could actually ask about why the discrepancy, in a new SO question.

Comment: **Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56)**
```In [1]: def split_combinations(L):
   ...:         for split in range(1, len(L)):
   ...:                 for combination in split_combinations(L[split:]):
   ...:                         yield [L[:split]] + combination
   ...:                 yield [L]```

```In [2]: print (list(split_combinations('abcd')))
[['a', 'b', 'cd'], ['a', 'bcd'], ['a', 'bcd'], ['abcd'], ['ab', 'cd'], ['abcd'], ['abcd']]``` ----same as @MarcinFabrykowski's

Comment: Python 2.7.8 (default, Jul  2 2014, 19:48:49), iPython: `In [1]: def split_combinations(L):
   ...:     for split in range(1, len(L)):
   ...:         for combination in split_combinations(L[split:]):
   ...:             yield [L[:split]] + combination
   ...:     yield [L]
   ...:

In [2]: print (list(split_combinations('abcd')))
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'cd'], ['a', 'bc', 'd'], ['a', 'bcd'], ['ab',
'c', 'd'], ['ab', 'cd'], ['abc', 'd'], ['abcd']]`

Comment: Figured out the discrepancy. I get the incorrect result if the `yield [L]` is indented twice instead of once. Make sure that it is indented only once and you should get the correct answer.