# Combination of word of string only replacing space

Tags: string, python-2.7

I am trying to find the all combination of words of string in particular format for example

```
string="hello python world"
```

the output format must be like

```
'hello python world, hellopython world, hello pyhtonworld, hellopythonworld'
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27263155/python-find-all-possible-word-combinations-with-a-sequence-of-characters-word

Comment: thanks for the solution.