# How to make a python script to generate all possible combinations of a particular character set in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I need a code that can generate all possible combinations of letters. It needs to be a generator function made to generate all combinations and return them to the previous call using the yield function. It needs to accept only one value: `length`, that specifies the length of the newly produced script.

This is what I have got so far:

```
characters = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "~", "`", "!", "@", "#", "$", "%", "^", "&", "*", "(", ")", "_", "-", "+", "=", "{", "}", "[", "]", "|", "\\", ":", ";", '"', "'", "<", ">", ".", "/", "?"]

def combo(length)
    #Future combo generation code
    yield combos
    return
```

Required output running `print(combo(2))` for example:

```
['aa', 'ab', 'ac', 'ad', 'ae', 'af', 'ag', ...]
```

This code will be needed to generate up to 20 character combinations.

Comment: Here some similar question I found [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27263155/python-find-all-possible-word-combinations-with-a-sequence-of-characters-word)  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45990454/generating-all-possible-combinations-of-characters-in-a-string)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generating all possible combinations of characters in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45990454/generating-all-possible-combinations-of-characters-in-a-string)

Comment: What do you intended to do with this? I don't think a brute force attack with a character set of 87 characters and a length of 20 is feasible.

Comment: @GordonAitchJay My Goals are beyond your understanding.

Comment: @Manvi First link: Does not use the yield function. Second link: When using the function in a print line, it just prints `[<generator object foo at 0x7f9583240430>]`

Comment: What are you printing??...Second link works nice for me..

Comment: @Zero-nnkn Link seems to be a duplicate of the second link provided by @Manvi and as I said before when using the function in a print line, it just prints `[<generator object foo at 0x7f9583240430>]`.

Comment: @SamanwayKarjee, you want to use yield so that it will return `generator`. You need to iterate over it to print each combo or cast it to list type. I think you should read about yield and generator [here](https://realpython.com/introduction-to-python-generators/)

Comment: @Manvi Seems to be a technical issue...When I tried it again it started working. But my question is not related to the second link anyways. My question is how can I run something like `list = combo(8)` where it sets the list to all the possible 8-digit combinations of the characters list.

Comment: @Zero-nnkn The truth is that I was just using print as an example. I want to be able to use the function like `list = combo(8)` where 8 is the number of digits WITHOUT using for loops because efficiency is VERY important in my script.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve just add it with your question as required output..

Comment: @Manvi Ok, let me do that real quick.

Comment: @Manvi Done, did it just now.

Answer (score -3):

may be useful

```
characters_for_combinations   = [ "a", "b", "c"]
from itertools import permutations
print(list(permutations(characters_for_combinations  )))
```

Comment: ...This crashed Visual Studio Code...

Answer (score -3):

I hope this answers your question.

```
import string
import random

def combo(length):
    code = random.choices(string.ascii_letters + string.punctuation, k=length)
    yield code
    
code = combo(20)
print(code)
print(*code)
```

The result

```
<generator object combo at 0x7fc78cef3ba0>
['r', 'N', '>', 'G', 'j', 'F', 'E', ')', 'C', '^', ':', 'z', 'q', 'o', '^', 'T', 'y', 's', 'y', '#']
```

Check here about the module used:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#functions-for-sequences
https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#module-string